# mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to add object to the array from a dictionary . In else part I am getting this error

> mutating method sent to immutable object'

```
NSMutableDictionary *selectedDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [selectedDict setObject:editedLineItem forKey:@"Text"];
    [selectedDict setObject:@"fa-check" forKey:@"IconClass"];
    NSMutableArray *tagListDictionary = [NSMutableArray new];
    [tagListDictionary addObject:selectedTagsArray];
    LineItemsStorage *linestorage = [LineItemsStorage sharedManager];
    if(![linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"Id"])
    {
        [linestorage.selectedLineItemsAndTagsArray addObject:selectedDict];
    }
    else{        [[linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"LineItems"]addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedDict]];
    }
```

> -[**NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001154a1d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000114f15deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001154a1cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115497b0a -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 106
>       4   FlatPebble                          0x000000010f276014 -[LineItemViewController okayAction] + 836
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000113809a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000011397ce67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000011397d143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000011397c263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000011387c99f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000011387d6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000113828dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000113802553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
>       13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153c7301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153bd22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153bc6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001153bc0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000116e5cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       18  UIKit                               0x0000000113807f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       19  ***********                         0x000000010f348c2f main + 111
>       20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000115d9992d start + 1
>   )

Comment: I suspect that the object for key `LineItems` is immutable and do not use `valueForKey:` unless you really really need KVC.

Comment: Only use valueForKey: if you can explain to a code reviewer why you use valueForKey: and not objectForKey:

Comment: In packages Array , there are two objects at which I must send these values to  linestorage.packagesArray

Comment: Mostly likely valueForKey returns immutable array which you are trying to add object to.

Comment: Chintu show me your selectedTagArray.What objects do you have in selectedTagArray? and where did you get that?

Comment: Your problem is that you're adding an object to `lineStorage.selectedLineItemsAndTagsArray` (which is an **immutable** `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray`). This is your key: `[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object`. It says you're sending an `insertObject:atIndex:` method to a `NSArray` and it should be a `NSMutableArray`. **Remember to use the Mutable subclasses if you pretend to modify your objects or their contents**. Change your `selectedLineItemsAndTagsArray` property to be a `NSMutableArray` and you should be fine (probably your `packagesArray` too)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 NSMutableDictionary *selectedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary new]mutableCopy];
    [selectedDict setObject:editedLineItem forKey:@"Text"];
    [selectedDict setObject:@"fa-check" forKey:@"IconClass"];
    NSMutableArray *tagListDictionary = [[NSMutableArray new]mutableCopy];
    [tagListDictionary addObject:selectedTagsArray];
    LineItemsStorage *linestorage = [LineItemsStorage sharedManager];
    if(![linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"Id"])
    {
        [linestorage.selectedLineItemsAndTagsArray addObject:selectedDict];
    }
    else{        [[linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"LineItems"]addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedDict]];
    }
```

Comment: `mutableCopy` makes no difference in this cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `packagesArray` contains an array containing one or more objects that have a `LineItems` property (that happens to also be an array); your problem is here:

`[[linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"LineItems"]addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedDict]]`

Breaking it down it is equivalent to:

```
 NSArray* packagesLineItems = [linestorage.packagesArray valueForKey:@"LineItems"];
 NSMutableArray* selected = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedDict];
 [packagesLineItems addObject:selected];
```

So your problem is either the return type of valueForKey (when called on an array), or the action you're trying to do on it.